# Qual a função de "use_aliases=True" em emoji.emojize?

Tags: python

Estou acompanhando um curso de Python e nele foi explicado como importar bibliotecas e tal, e para se usar [esta biblioteca](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emoji/) (como exemplo) foi dito para usar este comando

```
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbsup:', use_aliases=True))
```

Mas não entendi esta parte

```
use_aliases=True
```

O quê isto significa? Para quê serve e qual sua função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O parämetro use_aliases, de acordo com a documentação:

```
 use_aliases: (optional) Enable emoji aliases.  See ``emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ALIAS``.
```

Serve para ampliar a quantidade de emoticons, além destes (oficiais):
http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Aceita estes (adicionais):
https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/